# Raise HTTPException not being called

Tags: python, flask, fastapi

I have the following code:

```
@events_router.delete("/events/{event_id}", status_code=204)
def delete_event(*, event_id: int) -> None:
    for event in EVENTS:
        if event['id'] == event_id:
            del EVENTS[event_id-1]
            print("event id = " + str(event_id) + " deleted!")
            break
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=404,
            detail=f"Event with ID {event_id} not found"
        )
```

If I add an event and delete it by sending the correct id i.e. 1 the item gets deleted fine, however if I try to delete any item that is not the correct id then it gives a 204 status code rather than 404 with the message detail, see below:

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64831 - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64831 - "GET /openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:64832 - "POST /events/ HTTP/1.1" 201 Created
event id = 1 deleted!
INFO:     127.0.0.1:65016 - "DELETE /events/2 HTTP/1.1" 204 No Content
INFO:     127.0.0.1:65054 - "DELETE /events/5 HTTP/1.1" 204 No Content
INFO:     127.0.0.1:65076 - "DELETE /events/0 HTTP/1.1" 204 No Content
INFO:     127.0.0.1:65114 - "DELETE /events/3 HTTP/1.1" 204 No Content
```

Why is the HTTPException not being raised here, if the id is not correct?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What does `EVENTS` look like, and what `event_id` are you sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missplaced your raise statement. Now it's inside the loop and because there are no events it doesn't even go inside.

It should be:

```
@events_router.delete("/events/{event_id}", status_code=204)
def delete_event(*, event_id: int) -> None:
    for event in EVENTS:
        if event['id'] == event_id:
            del EVENTS[event_id-1]
            print("event id = " + str(event_id) + " deleted!")
            break
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=404,
            detail=f"Event with ID {event_id} not found"
        )
```

And to simplify the code, consider to create event mapping:

```
EVENT_BY_ID = {event["id"]: event for event in EVENTS}

@events_router.delete("/events/{event_id}", status_code=204)
def delete_event(*, event_id: int) -> None:
    if event_id in EVENT_BY_ID:
        ...
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: This is a textbook use-case for an `else` clause on the `for` loop: `for event in EVENTS: ... else: raise HTTPException(...)`. There's no need for a flag to remember if you exited the loop with a `break` or ran out of events: the loop itself remembers.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that the raise was incorrectly inside the loop.  That did the trick.